# jq: command not found in GitLab CI file

Tags: bash, shell, gitlab, gitlab-ci

In .gitlab-ci.yml

```
stages:
  - test-jq

    test-jq:
      stage: test-jq
      image: ruby:2.5
      script:
        - apt-get update
        - apt-get install -y git jq
        - git config --global user.email "$GITLAB_USER_EMAIL"
        - git config --global user.name "$GITLAB_USER_NAME"
        - LAST_COMMIT_SHA=$(
          curl -s \
           --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:$CLONE_KEY" \
           "$CI_API_V4_URL/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/repository/commits/$CI_COMMIT_SHA" |\
           jq -r '.parent_ids | del(.[] | select(. == "'$CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA'")) | .[-1]'

      )
```

throwing an error:
/bin/bash: line 158:  jq: command not found

Comment: If you read the logs for the `apt-get install -y git jq` step, do they reflect success? What's the PATH? Where is the jq binary placed at? If you run `ls -l /usr/bin/jq` (replacing with wherever you think the executable should be), is it present? If it _is_ present, does `ldd /usr/bin/jq` say that its libraries are all successfully loadable?

Answer (score 7):

Another approach is to set all the installation part *before* your scripts, as [shown here](https://github.com/monetha/TrustReputationSmartContracts/blob/b5525c7acff8a5a6f396a1cc61db2985792745ef/.gitlab-ci.yml), using [`before_script`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#before_script):

```yaml
image: node:latest

before_script:
  - apt-get -qq update
  - apt-get install -y jq
```

That way, you can make sure the environment is correctly set up once your script starts.