# How can I use an output from my Gitlab pipeline, as a value in the pipeline?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a pipeline that builds an AMI image, but I'd also like to be able to use that AMI ID in an additional stage afterwards.I'm not sure how to capture an output (the AMI ID) as a value for further down the pipeline.

Here's my **.gitlab-ci.yml** file:

```
image:
  name: hashicorp/packer:latest
  entrypoint:
    - '/usr/bin/env'
    - 'PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'

before_script:
  - packer --version

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

get_packer:
  stage: build
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - packer
  script:
    - echo "Fetching packer"
    - wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/packer/1.5.5/packer_1.5.5_linux_amd64.zip
    - unzip packer_1.5.5_linux_amd64.zip
    - chmod +x packer

deploy_packer:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "Deploying Packer Build"
    - cd aws
    - packer build -only="*rhel-stig*" .
```

Here's the tail-end of the **output** from my pipeline that spits out the AMI ID:

```
Build 'rhel.amazon-ebs.rhel-stig' finished after 8 minutes 17 seconds.
==> Wait completed after 8 minutes 17 seconds
==> Builds finished. The artifacts of successful builds are:
--> rhel.amazon-ebs.rhel-stig: AMIs were created:
us-east-1: ami-08155b7eaa9e0274f
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
Job succeeded
```

Notice how it outputs the region and the ami-ID, how can I use that AMI ID in the same pipeline if I want to add onto the pipeline like so?

theoretical **.gitlab-ci.yml** file

```
image:
  name: hashicorp/packer:latest
  entrypoint:
    - '/usr/bin/env'
    - 'PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'

before_script:
  - packer --version

stages:
  - build
  - deploy
  - test

get_packer:
  stage: build
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - packer
  script:
    - echo "Fetching packer"
    - wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/packer/1.5.5/packer_1.5.5_linux_amd64.zip
    - unzip packer_1.5.5_linux_amd64.zip
    - chmod +x packer

deploy_packer:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "Deploying Packer Build"
    - cd aws
    - packer build -only="*rhel-stig*" .

test_image:
   stage: test
   script: 
     - (Do something with the outputted AMI ID from the deploy stage)
```

**Update:**

New error after initial additions

```
Build 'rhel.amazon-ebs.rhel-stig' finished after 9 minutes 22 seconds.
==> Wait completed after 9 minutes 22 seconds
==> Builds finished. The artifacts of successful builds are:
--> rhel.amazon-ebs.rhel-stig: AMIs were created:
us-east-1: ami-04b363eecd4fd841a
--> rhel.amazon-ebs.rhel-stig: AMIs were created:
us-east-1: ami-04b363eecd4fd841a
$ AMI_ID=$(jq -r '.builds[-1].artifact_id' manifest.json | cut -d ":" -f2)
/bin/bash: line 137: jq: command not found
Uploading artifacts for failed job
00:00
Uploading artifacts...
WARNING: image.env: no matching files. Ensure that the artifact path is relative to the working directory 
ERROR: No files to upload                          
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is configure the packer build to use the [manifest post-processor](https://developer.hashicorp.com/packer/docs/post-processors/manifest):

```
post-processor "manifest" {
    output = "manifest.json"
    strip_path = true
}
```

this will generate a json file which contains the AMI ID at the end of the build.

Then, you can use the `dotenv` artifacts construct to share variables with subsequent jobs.

Here's how it works:

```
deploy_packer:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "Deploying Packer Build"
    - cd aws
    - packer build -only="*rhel-stig*" .
    - AMI_ID=$(jq -r '.builds[-1].artifact_id' manifest.json | cut -d ":" -f2)
    - echo "AMI_ID=$AMI_ID" > image.env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: aws/image.env

test_image:
   stage: test
   script: 
     - echo $AMI_ID
   needs:
     - job: build
       artifacts: true
```

Comment: I just updated the post with the new error I got, after trying to run the first additional command `$ AMI_ID=$(jq -r '.builds[-1].artifact_id' manifest.json | cut -d ":" -f2)` it gives this error `/bin/bash: line 137: jq: command not found`

Comment: @MitchellPrivett install `jq` in your pipeline

Comment: I tried this solution to do so https://stackoverflow.com/a/72237139/20267449 I tried it with apt-get, apt and yum and they all gave me the same respective error for each one`apt-get: command not found`

Comment: `apk add jq` seems to be working

Comment: @mitchellprivett yes, the image is alpine based so you need to use `apk`. Did you get everything working?

Comment: This command in my pipeline `echo "AMI_ID=$AMI_ID" > ~/image.env` keeps giving me this error `WARNING: ~/image.env: no matching files. Ensure that the artifact path is relative to the working directory` I tried it with three variations: `image.env` ,`./image.env` and `~/image.env` and got the same errors. It's causing my ami ID in the final stage to output like this `echo $AMI_ID`

Comment: That did the trick, appreciate the help!

Comment: @MitchellPrivett great, I'm glad